# Use MultiSelectListPreference ofr Android PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I'm use Android ICS SDK and I would like to do a PreferenceScreen which use MultiSelectListPreference (avalaible for API Level 11&+.

I just want to persist the value in SharedPref, refresh the summary of the MultiSelectListPreference and refresh the dialog list.

Here's my code :

```
Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.newgame);
    mMultiCharacters.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor settingsEditor = settings.edit();
    settingsEditor.putStringSet( preference.getKey() , (Set<String>) newValue);
    settingsEditor.commit();
    //display new summary
    initChar();
    return false;
}
```

XML part :

```
    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:entries="@array/characterNames"
        android:entryValues="@array/characterNames"
        android:key="pref_characters"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:title="Chars :" />
```

The behavior is quite strange. The dialog list doesn't refresh… some ideas ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well.. I used `MultiSelectListPreference` once, and here is what I "think" ..

You are returning `false` in the `onPreferenceChange` listener, which I think it doesn't only NOT commit the changes, but also may be reverting to the previous values. I'm aware that you are committing the changes through `settingsEditor` but may be the `false` return is reverting back the old values, so I suggest returning true.

One more thing, the `newValue` object is actually a `HashSet` which contains the newly selected values, so you can use it to do whatever you want but you don't have to use it to commit changes if you are returning true.
Good Luck.